# One who can't keep secrets?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, word-request, vocabulary

Some one who is not good at keeping secrets. In my native language it is called "chugalkhor" but it's a slang. So I can't translate it.

What do you call such a person who can't keep secrets because his instincts don't let him.

Comment: See the *synonyms* section for **blabbermouth**: 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blabbermouth

Comment: It could be *newsmonger*

Comment: If the answers on ELU were not good enough, please explain what it is exactly you are looking for, which is not already there:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183214/one-who-cant-keep-secrets

Comment: I think this question needs more context. A little kid who "tells on" his little brother (as in, "Mom! Billy ate a cookie!") is a _tattletale_; a criminal who "spills the beans" during interrogation is a _rat_; a housewife who can't shut up about seeing her neighbor holding hands with a man who is not her husband could be a _gossiper, meddler,_ or _busybody_. What kind of secret are we talking about here? The suggestion by @CopperKettle is a good one, though; _blabbermouth_ would fit just about all of those scenarios.

Comment: In "The Wire", I've seen _snitch_ used quite frequently.

Comment: I also speak a language which has a word for those who can't keep secrets. These people aren't trusted within their society and are not allowed to participate in rituals. Having spent many years looking for an English equivalent, I can only wish you courage and good fortune. I will also be very happy if someone contributes an answer!

Comment: (continued) The people I'm referring to aren't mocked or despised - and the word (a bird's name) used to describe these people isn't pejorative. They simply cannot find it in themselves to hide the truth from somebody when they feel the other party should know. Is your word like this? If so, would "Blabbermouth" suit yours or be too critical, as in my case?

Comment: @user42307 Would this help? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19556/one-word-noun-for-truth-teller

Comment: @jinawee Yes,  a *truth teller is more to the point.  I think we might also look to corporate culture for terms to describe workers who are too honest: no only to make difficult decisions, but also to share in the secrecy of business.

Answer (score 4):

A slang term for a person who can't keep a secret is a [blabbermouth](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blabbermouth).

Someone who talks a lot about other people, including about their personal information, is a [gossip or gossiper](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gossip) (you can say it either way).

Edit:

I thought of another one: [loudmouth](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/loudmouth). A loudmouth can be someone who talks too loud, but they can also be someone who blurts out secrets without thinking.

Comment: I've just recalled a good use of the word 'blabbermouth' in one great movie:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EC1l1J8Voc#t=211
("put these in water, blabbermouth!" - after the nurse spills the beans, telling that the key hero was expelled from the hospital, not simply discharged)